# air tap doesnt work on hololens 1 even with the new release v2.0.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

On the mode "holographic" from unity, the air tap is working.
But when i deploy the scene on the device (HoloLens 1), it's not working and even with the new release.
I find a post many months ago about it, on the issues, explaining that it was "normal", but with the new release released, i was wondering if it's still normal now ?

i have tried 3 components : "interactable", "pointerhandler" and "inputactionhandler".
None of them is working.

I expect the air tap to work when deploying the scene to the HoloLens 1

Answer (score 0):

@Lepiaf. Does air tap work for you in the Example Hub demo (https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases/download/v2.0.0/MRTKExamplesHub082619_HoloLens1_x86.zip)?

If so, would you be willing to provide a small project that demonstrates the issue you are seeing?

Thanks!
David

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but when I'm trying to install this example I'm having this error : (0x800B0109). And when i tried to solve it, it didn't work because the certificate is not trusted. I have tested the official example scene : MixedRealityToolkit.examples/Demos/Handtracking/Scenes/HandInteractionExamples. The air tap on this scene works on Unity but it did not work on HoloLens 1.

Comment: I will test the HandInteractionExample on my HoloLens. Also, what is the version of the operating system on your HoloLens?

Comment: One other question, what version of Unity are you using?

Thanks!

Comment: I have confirmed that when building the HandInteractionExamples and deploying to my HoloLens (1st gen), Air Tap works as expected. I can press buttons, move objects, interact with UI elements, etc.

My configuration is: Unity 2018.4.8f1, Windows Holographic  10.0.17763.134.

Comment: I m working with Unity2019.1.7f1 and i have the version 10.0.14393.2189

Comment: I will try to reproduce it with Unity 2019.1. I highly recommend updating your HoloLens using Windows Update. You should be offered 10.0.17763 which is the latest version for HoloLens (1st gen).

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I will ask around here to see if there are any known issues on that build.

Comment: @davidkline-ms I am having a similar issue with Unity 2019.2 and v2.0.0 on Hololens 1. E.g. I can select buttons with air tab gestures but the linked events are not called. Do you have any clue what could be the issue?

Comment: @crani, do you have a small repro you can share?

Comment: I had "WSA Holographic remoting supported" checked under build settings, that was the issue...